# Zend_Cache: After loading cached data, character encoding seems messed up

Tags: php, zend-framework, character-encoding, zend-cache

First; On my development server (localhost; default XAMPP on OSX) everything works fine, though when I deploy the exact same code (and data) to the staging server (managed Apache2 on Redhat) it breaks.

I'm caching some data using Zend_Cache using the File backend and auto-serialization.
Special characters used in the original data display fine, though when they are loaded from cache they're all garbled up.

Anyone got a clue?

PS. Instead of *just* a workaround, I'm looking for a way to understand what might go "wrong" on the staging server. What could possibly mess this up?

**UPDATE**
The data I'm caching is UTF-8 encoded.

**UPDATE**
When looking at the raw cache files (of a serialized array) there i See one big difference;
The data cached on my localhost shows no newlines when the (identical) data cached on the staging server **does** show newlines.

**UPDATE**
Local server runs `PHP 5.3`, staging server runs `PHP 5.2.10`

**UPDATE**
Running on Zend FW 1.10.8

Comment: Are both environments running the same version of the Zend Framework?

Comment: yes, all code is exactly the same - including any libraries used. (ZF version; 1.10.8)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have almost identical state like you ,

development machine is windows + php 5.3

development machine is Linux + php 5.2.14

ZF version is 1.10

the only difference i had is : i used to add `mb_internal_encoding("UTF-8");` in the bootstrap class

FYI , I used to cache text (arabic language ) from database all encoded UTF8 
when i open the file i see the arabic text as expected .

**UPDATE**  :
1- here is my complete initCache function just to make it clear

```
public function _initCache() {
        mb_internal_encoding("UTF-8");
        $frontendOptions = array(
            'automatic_serialization' => TRUE,
            'lifetime' => 86400
        );
        $backendOptions = array(
            'cache_dir' => APPLICATION_PATH . "/configs/cache/",
                ///'cache_dir' => sys_get_temp_dir(),
        );
        $cache = Zend_Cache::factory('Core', 'File', $frontendOptions, $backendOptions);
        Zend_Db_Table_Abstract::setDefaultMetadataCache($cache);
        Zend_Registry::set("cache", $cache);
    }
```

**Explanation :** 
1-Any php version earlier than PHP 6 doesn't have native support for UTF-8 ,
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/716703/what-is-coming-in-php-6

2-making  php 5.3 or 5.2 deal with UTF8 by using [ICONV](http://php.net/manual/en/book.iconv.php) or [MB_STRING](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mbstring.php)

simply by using  `var_dump(mb_internal_encoding());`

you can tell that php using **ISO-8859-1** internally ,

you can override it by `var_dump(mb_internal_encoding("UTF-8"));`

it would output true (it success to override the internal encoding  )

to be honest i don't know if there is better solution  or [how bad it is ??](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4045060/how-bad-is-mb-internal-encodingutf-8) ,

if you had any better i would be happy to adopt it :)

**UPDATE 2** 
in case you don't want to use that function , 
open this file `"Zend/Cache/Backend/File.php"` and go to the line 976 
change this :

```
protected function _filePutContents($file, $string)
{

    $result = false;
    $f = @fopen($file, 'ab+');
    if ($f) {
        if ($this->_options['file_locking']) @flock($f, LOCK_EX);
        fseek($f, 0);
        ftruncate($f, 0);
        $tmp = @fwrite($f, $string);
        if (!($tmp === FALSE)) {
            $result = true;
        }
        @fclose($f);
    }
    @chmod($file, $this->_options['cache_file_umask']);
    return $result;
}
```

to be this :

```
protected function _filePutContents($file, $string)
{
    $string = mb_convert_encoding($string   , "UTF-8" , "ISO-8859-1"); // i didn't test it , use it at your own risk and i'd rather stick with the first solution 
    $result = false;
    $f = @fopen($file, 'ab+');
    if ($f) {
        if ($this->_options['file_locking']) @flock($f, LOCK_EX);
        fseek($f, 0);
        ftruncate($f, 0);
        $tmp = @fwrite($f, $string);
        if (!($tmp === FALSE)) {
            $result = true;
        }
        @fclose($f);
    }
    @chmod($file, $this->_options['cache_file_umask']);
    return $result;
}
```

i didn't test manually but it should work as expected

Glad  it helped !

Comment: I've added the setting of mb_internal_encoding to the bootstrap on the staging server and flushed the cache. Now all data loaded from cache isn't garbled anymore.
The weird thing is, after removing mb_internal_encoding and flushing cache again, the problem is still fixed.
I'm gonna wait and see if it holds up. Might be a good idea to add it to the default bootstrap anyway.

Comment: I've added it to the default bootstrapping class and it seems to be holding up. No more garbles in the data.
Thanks for you answer!

Comment: Cheers for the update, but I'd rather not change any code in ZF files. I could implement a custom backend based on Zend_Cache_Backend_File, but just setting the mb_internal_encoding() in the bootstrap would be be easier to maintain and might even prevent other character encoding issues not related to zend_cache.

Comment: **UPDATE** after setting mb_internal_encoding(), no newlines on the staging server's cache files anymore.

Comment: i'd rather stick with mb_internal_encoding("UTF-8"); and keep everything nice , tidy and less time consuming :P

Comment: @Maurice's update  , sorry i was bit distracted yesterday , could you please show me some result from  the cache

Answer (score 0):

Can you check LC_LANG and other language variables?
Apart from your problem :

I have problem with my cache files, between my hosting and local server (one debian, one ubuntu) 
I discovered the problem, when serializing \r causes problem. One system saves \r but ignores counting.

So I before serializing, remove all \r from the string. That removed!