# How bad is mb_internal_encoding("UTF-8");?

Tags: php, encoding, utf-8, internationalization

After answering [Zend_Cache: After loading cached data, character encoding seems messed up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4041968/zend-cache-after-loading-cached-data-character-encoding-seems-messed-up/4043064#4043064)

I use it to change the PHP's internal encoding , its originally `ISO-8859-1`,

so I need to change the encoding of every non English input value, but using it I force PHP to convert every value to `UTF-8`, as you might see in the question linked above.

I am Caching arabic text in files using `Zend_cache`, I wasn't be able to do it without that function.

I need to know: How bad is to use this function `mb_internal_encoding("UTF-8");`?

I had adopt to use this function in every project I opt in , all of them are using non-english characters

Comment: Why would using `mb_internal_decoding()` be bad? Why do you need to use it in the first place?

Comment: I had updated my question , please check it out