# Zend framework caching encoding

Tags: zend-framework, zend-cache

I'm developing a Zend application. It caches menu items to reduce database transactions. I'm looking for a way to set encoding of cached files to UTF8. In `application.ini` I have:

```
resources.view.encoding = "UTF-8"
```

Though seems not working.

**Update:**

I can't find `_initCache` function or any other code responsible of caching. Caching is only specified in `application.ini` :

```
resources.cache.frontEnd = core
resources.cache.backEnd = file
resources.cache.frontEndOptions.lifetime = 1200
resources.cache.frontEndOptions.automatic_serialization = true
resources.cache.backEndOptions.lifetime = 3600
resources.cache.backEndOptions.cache_dir = APPLICATION_PATH "/../cache"
pluginPaths.CMS_Application_Resource   = APPLICATION_PATH "/../library/CMS/Application/Resource"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm looking for a way to set encoding of cached files to UTF8

Zend_Cache doesn't have an encoding option and doesn't handle encodings!
Zend_Cache simply stores data as a binary stream so if you store UTF-8 text you store a byte stream and if you store ASCII text you store a byte stream. **YOU** have to know which type of data you stored within the cache and how to use it.
If you don't have `magic_quote_runtime` enabled you get the same bytes you stored before else disable this deprecated PHP-INI-Setting (and all other magic quotes settings).

Answer (score 2):

In layout have this?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en" xml:lang="en">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
```

Comment: Yes. Everything else is OK with encoding. Only parts loaded from cache are not parsed as UTF8 characters.

Comment: please read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4041968/zend-cache-after-loading-cached-data-character-encoding-seems-messed-up/4043064#4043064

Comment: Well, I can't find which peace of code is responsible of caching. See update